# Generate all possible permutations of characters with a given maximum length

Tags: ruby

I want something like `["a", "b", "c"].all_possibilities(4)` to produce: `abc acb bac bca cab cba abca abcb abcc acba acbb acbc ...` up to the last possible <strike>combination</strike> permutation using at most `4` characters from `abc`.

I tried permutations, but I don't think that's the case: `%w[a b c].permutation.map &:join` just permute, so length is no greater than three. Any help?

Comment: A naive implementation has N nested loops where N is your maximum length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about ?

```
class Array
  def all_possibilities(range)
    return permutation(range).to_a if range < size

    (size..range).flat_map do |i|
      permutation(range - i).flat_map do |e|
        (self + e).permutation.to_a
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This returns an array of arrays of strings.

```
%w(a c).all_possibilities(3)
# => [["a", "c", "a"], ["a", "a", "c"], ["c", "a", "a"],
#     ["c", "a", "a"], ["a", "a", "c"], ["a", "c", "a"],
#     ["a", "c", "c"], ["a", "c", "c"], ["c", "a", "c"],
#     ["c", "c", "a"], ["c", "a", "c"], ["c", "c", "a"],
#     ["a", "c"], ["c", "a"]]
```

To print it, you could just do `result.map(&:join).join(', ')`.

*ps: there is duplicates you could just avoid using `uniq`. It happens because you can have twice the same letter in an array like `%w(a c a)`.*