# Generate all possibles combinations of an array with a length within a given range

Tags: ruby, arrays, combinations

How can I generate all possible combinations of elements of an array with a length within a given range? E.g.:

```
('a'..'f').to_a.all_possibilities(3, 5)
```

should produce an array like:

```
['abc', 'abd', 'abe', 'abf', ..., 'abcde', 'abcdf', 'abcda', ...]
```

including from `"abc"` (three characters) up to the last possible combination of `('a'..'f').to_a` with five characters length. I have no idea how to do this. Any help?

Comment: To clarify, is `'abcda'` an error? Are repeats allowed? Is `'aaa'` something you want in the results? Also, how does this differ from [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375055/generate-all-possible-permutations-of-characters-with-a-given-maximum-length)?

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-combination

Comment: @Amadan Combination does not include repetitions.

Comment: @Amadan I want repetitions. I need to generate all possibilities. And my previous question I dont ask for a minimum length, so the minium length will be always de array.size.

Comment: @sawa Sorry, I don't know this concept.

Comment: @sawa: I know that - but the OP's example explicitly includes `'abcda'`, which does imply repetitions.

Comment: @user1986332 What do you mean? You are the one who used the word "combination". And you don't know it?

Comment: @Amadan Sorry about that. I mistook the intention. The question was badly worded.

Comment: @sawa: Why are you so arrogant? I know what the word combination means, for me an combination locker can contains the key '7227121', an chord combination can be "Am, Em, Am, C". I said that I don't understand the concept, of no including repetitions.

Comment: @user1986332 I don't know what you mean by saying that I am arrogant. I would call "Am, Em, Am, C" a chord **sequence** rather than a chord combination. You seem to be understanding the concept of not including repetitions. I don't understand why you say you do not understand that.

Comment: @user1986332 At first, I could not understand what you meant by `an combination locker can contains the key '7227121'`. Now, I guess you meant "**a** combination **lock** can **have** the key '7227121'". Well, in this case, a combination (lock) is a combination of multiple locks. The number '7227121' is the key to the combination (lock), not combination itself.

Comment: @sawa Ok, sorry then, I understand it now.

Answer (score 64):

[`Array#combination`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-combination) is stdlib:

```
[1] pry(main)> a = ('a'..'f').to_a
=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
[2] pry(main)> a.combination(3).to_a
=> [["a", "b", "c"],
 ["a", "b", "d"],
 ["a", "b", "e"],
 ["a", "b", "f"],
 ["a", "c", "d"],
 ["a", "c", "e"],
 ["a", "c", "f"],
 ["a", "d", "e"],
 ["a", "d", "f"],
 ["a", "e", "f"],
 ["b", "c", "d"],
 ["b", "c", "e"],
 ["b", "c", "f"],
 ["b", "d", "e"],
 ["b", "d", "f"],
 ["b", "e", "f"],
 ["c", "d", "e"],
 ["c", "d", "f"],
 ["c", "e", "f"],
 ["d", "e", "f"]]
```

if you want all combinations of size min to max:

```
(min..max).flat_map{|size| a.combination(size).to_a }
```

If you want them converted to strings, just replace `.to_a` with `.map(&:join)`.

Comment: `+1` to you.Could you bit explain the line `(min..max).flat_map{|size| a.combination(size) }` ?

Comment: `a.combination(size)` produces an array of arrays, each of which is a unique combination that can be made from `a`. `(min..max)` is an inclusive [range](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html) starting with `min`, ending at `max`. [`flat_map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) enumerates over the values of the range yielding each one to the block and producing a result that concatenates all the block results.

Comment: How would you get all the combinations, including repeated use of the same element? Like ["a","a","a"], ["a","b","a"] would also be okay, and  ["a","b","a"] would be different to ["b","a","a"].

Comment: Nevermind. I worked out how to do it using the .repeated_permutation() method :)

Answer (score 13):

```
(3..5).flat_map{|n| ('a'..'f').to_a.combination(n).map(&:join)}
```

Edit: to meet OP's clarified intention, use `repeated_permutation`.

```
(3..5).flat_map{|n| ('a'..'f').to_a.repeated_permutation(n).map(&:join)}
```

Comment: Its not generate all possible combinations. I mean, my name is "Fernando". 8 characters length but the letter 'n' repeats twice, so 7 letters in total. And I do this: 

'array = ["F", "E", "R", "N", "A", "D", "O"]
puts (3..8).flat_map{|n| array.combination(n).map(&:join)}'

But its don't generate my name. And this code outputs few combinations, all possibilities should return a really large output.

Comment: @user1986332 the answers you have only works if your data array length is superior or equal to your range max int.

Comment: @user1986332 If so, then your question is badly worded. Usually when you say combination, it does not include repetition.

Comment: I use my name's example again and still not generating it.

Comment: @sawa That is the closer of my name that it generates : FERNAAAA
FERNAAAD
FERNAAAO
FERNAADD
FERNAADO
FERNAAOO
FERNADDD
FERNADDO
FERNADOO
FERNAOOO

Comment: @user1986332 Sorry. It should have been `repeated_permutation`, not `repeated_combination`. I edited it. (This also indicates that the word you should have used was "permutation", not "combination".) Now, it should work. Be aware that it will run pretty much longer. On my computer, it is taking minutes.

Comment: The length of the resulting array with `3..8` and `%[F E R N A D O]` would be `7^3 + 7^4 + 7^5 + 7^6 + 7^7 + 7^8 = 6725544`. It is running on my computer for several minutes, and it now reached around 1580000: one fourth of the way through. I doubt you really want this.

Answer (score 2):

You could modify my response to your previous question this way to get what you want.

```
class Array
  def all_possibilities(from, to)
    (from..to).flat_map do |i|
      if i < size
        permutation(i).to_a 
      else
        permutation(to - i).flat_map do |e|
          (self + e).permutation.to_a
        end
      end
    end.map(&:join)
  end
end

array = ["F", "E", "R", "N", "A", "D", "O"]
array.all_possibilities(3, 8)
```

Answer (score 2):

`

```
D = length of array
N = number of possible values. i.e a-z = 26
possible combinations = N ^ D
array = [possible values]

map26 = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnop'
map10 = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

combo = '' 
for 0...N ** D do |i|
  i.to_s(D).split(//).each do |v|  
    combo += map10[map26.index(v)].chr
  end
  puts combo
  combo = ''
end
```

`

EDIT: Excuse the brevity of above, hacked it out on an iPad while browsing for another answer. And I was so wrong.

Lets say you want all combinations from a-z for up to 3 columns.

All combinations are 26 * 26 * 26 = 26 ** 3 = 17576

Lets subtract 1 for 0 starting points of arrays = 17575

Also we need a mapping variables, map26 is a base 26 lookup for one column

```
map26 = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnop'
map10 = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

Back to our maximum combo

```
17575.to_s(26)
=> "ppp"
```

Extract the index of 'p' from map26 and put it in map10:

```
map10[map26.index('p')]   (add .chr for ruby ~ 1.8)
=> "z"
```

So if you slice and dice the "ppp" above you will get a maximum combo of "zzz"

You can also see from the mapping variables that "000" will map to "aaa"

I have modified the original code to include these changes.

With respect to the original question, you can use D to control the maximum length of the string and play with the starting value of the for loop to control the minimum length.