# Combination up to n

Tags: ruby, arrays, combinations

Given an array `a`, what is the best way to achieve its combinations up to the `n`-th? For example:

```
a = %i[a b c]
n = 2

# Expected => [[], [:a], [:b], [:c], [:a, b], [:b, :c], [:c, :a]]
```

Comment: do you want the combinations to be sorted? What values of n do you expect? How about the size of a?

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev No, it can start from the longest one, or in any order.

Comment: Nice question.. +1 I like it... :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate all possibles combinations of an array with a length within a given range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431582/generate-all-possibles-combinations-of-an-array-with-a-length-within-a-given-ran) ... or am I wrong?

Comment: Personally I think `combination` without a parameter should generate all.

Comment: @MarkThomas That may work when you want the powerset, but not when `n` is smaller than the cardinality of `A`; you need to pass the information `n`.

Comment: @MarkThomas It is not a duplicate of that question. Despite its title, it is about repeated permutation, not combination. The OP there misused the terminology.

Comment: @sawa. Correct, it should be an *optional* parameter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do as below :

```
a = %w[a b c]
n = 3

0.upto(n).flat_map { |i| a.combination(i).to_a }
# => [[], ["a"], ["b"], ["c"], ["a", "b"], 
# ["a", "c"], ["b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
def all_combis(a, n, b=[])
  n.zero? ? b.unshift([]) : all_combis(a, n-1, b.unshift(*a.combination(n)))
end

all_combis(%i[a b c], 0)
  #=> [[]]
all_combis(%i[a b c], 1)
  #=> [[], [:a], [:b], [:c]]
all_combis(%i[a b c], 2)
  #=> [[], [:a], [:b], [:c], [:a, :b], [:a, :c], [:b, :c]]
all_combis(%i[a b c], 3)
  #=> [[], [:a], [:b], [:c], [:a, :b], [:a, :c], [:b, :c], [:a, :b, :c]]
```

If order and efficiency are unimportant, this also works:

```
a.repeated_combination(n).map(&:uniq) << []

%i[a b c].repeated_combination(2).map(&:uniq) << []
  #=> [[:a], [:a, :b], [:a, :c], [:b], [:b, :c], [:c], []]
```

Comment: +1 for helping me to remember `repeated_combination`.. **recursion** technique is also good.