# Optimal Selection in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm

Given an array of values,

```
arr = [8,10,4,5,3,7,6,0,1,9,13,2]
```

`X` is an array of values can be chosen at a time where `X.length != 0` and `X.length < arr.length`

The chosen values are then fed into a function, score(), which will return a score based on the array of select values.

```
Example 1: 
X = [8]
score(X) = 71

Example 2:
X = [4]
score(X) = 36

Example 3:
X = [8,10,7]
score(X) = 51

Example 4:
X = [5,9,0]
score(X) = 4
```

The function score() here is a blackbox and we can't modify how the function works, we just provide an input and the function will return the score output.

My problem: How to get the lowest score for each set of numbers?

Meaning, if X is an array that has only 1 value, and I feed all the different values in arr, each value will return me a different score value, and I find which arr value provides the lowest score.

If X is an array of 3 values, I feed a combination of all the different possible values in arr, with each different set of 3 values returning a different score and finding the lowest score.

This is simple enough to do if my arr is small. However if I have an array of 50 or even 100 values, how can I create an algorithm that would provide the lowest score based on the number of input values

Comment: Are you asking how to generate all subsets of `arr` or are you asking how to handle the computational explosion?

Comment: How to handle the computational load. Finding a combination of arr is easy enough, arr.combination(3) for example. But then I will have a very large enumerable, if I run all the values through the score() function it will take a very long time, especially on a very large array.

Comment: *"if I have an array of 50 or even 100 values..."* - Based on your description of the situation (*"The function score() here is a blackbox..."*), the **only** possible solution is to simply try every possible permutation of subsets. So for example, if `arr` contains 50 elements, then you must check **all `(2^50 - 1) == 1,125,899,906,842,623`** possibilities!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate all possibles combinations of an array with a length within a given range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431582/generate-all-possibles-combinations-of-an-array-with-a-length-within-a-given-ran)

Comment: @d123 - open the blackbox and tell us the score specifics. If the question is  for any general function then the answer is simple - you can't. You just have to enumerate

Comment: The best you could do is make the enumerable computation lazy. This way, you will generate the next subset when you need it, instead generating all subsets at the start. There are heuristics you can try based on the *"closeness"* of the values you get, but worst case scenario - there is nothing better you can do.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev So if I really have to enum all values, what is the fastest way of doing that? I can't just do a while loop and run all the values through the function, that would take a very long time, is there anyway to speed things up exponentially?

Comment: @d123 buy a quantum computer.

Comment: @ndn could you elaborate more on how to make the computation lazy? Also, what kind of heuristics methods can I try? Any links you know of that I can read up on? ndn seriously?!

Comment: Get a *lazy* list of all values for X: `1.upto(arr.length).flat_map { |n| arr.combination(n).lazy }`. Then, loop through them all by applying the `score()` function. Regarding the heuristics, this is basically just saying "make an estimation, based on a subset of the possible results".

Comment: @d123 for making it [lazy](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-lazy). As for trying heuristics - take a look at [Bayesian classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) for starters, even though it highly depends on the output distribution.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**: If you don't know anything about `score`, then you can't speed it up.

In order to optimize `score` itself, you would have to know how it works. After all "optimizing" simply means "does the same thing more efficient", but how can you know if it *really* does "the same thing" if you don't know what "the same thing" is? Plus, speeding up `score` will not help you with the *combinatorial explosion* anyway. The number of combinations grows so fast, that any speedups to `score` will be quickly eaten up by slightly larger inputs.

In order to optimize how you apply `score`, you would again need to know something about it. If you knew something about `score`, you could, for example, only generate combinations that you know will yield different values, or combinations that you know will only yield larger values. In other words, you could exploit some structure in the output of `score` in order to reduce the input size. However, we don't know the structure of the output of `score`, in fact, we don't even know if there is some structure *at all*! So we can't exploit it. Plus, there would have to be some *extreme* redundancy and regularity in the structure, in order for a significant reduction in input size.

[In his comment, @ndn suggested applying some form of machine learning to discover structure in the output.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847177/optimal-selection-in-ruby#comment66983341_39847177). How well this works depends on what kind of structure the output has. And of course, this again assumes that there even *is* some structure to discover, which we don't know. And again, even if there were some structure, it would have to very redundant and regular to make up for the combinatorial explosion of the input space.

Really, brute force is the only way. Our last straw is going to be parallelization. Maybe, if we distribute the problem across enough CPU cores, we can tackle it? Unfortunately, the combinatorial explosion in the input space is *still* really going to hurt you:

If we assume that we have a 10THz CPU (i.e. a thousand times faster than the fastest currently available CPU), *and* we assume that we can compute `score` in a single clock cycle, *and* we assume that we have a computer with 10 million cores (again, that's a thousand times larger than the largest supercomputers), it's still going to take over 400 years to find the optimal selection for an input array as small as 100 numbers. And even if we make our CPU a billion times faster and the computer a billion times bigger, simply doubling the size of the array to 200 items will increase the runtime to 500 trillion years.

There is a reason why we call *combinatorial explosion* "combinatorial **explosion**", after all.